# Comparator not sorting right

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

So, I'm trying to implement a genetic algorithm for a project and for some reason after running for several generations it shows just one array over and over again. After commenting out the sorting function it stopped doing that. Thus I figured that something is wrong with my sorting function:

```
private double[][] sortPopulation(final double[][] popArr) {
    Arrays.sort(popArr, new Comparator<double[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
            return Double.compare(o1[popArr[0].length - 1], o2[popArr[0].length - 1]);
        }
    });
    return popArr;
}
```

The function gets a two dimensional array which is my population running from `[0-99][0-32]` The last value in the second dimension represents the value given by a fitness function which is the value I want to sort the population by.

What I get in the first generation is:

```
1. [22 20 1 8 29 32 16 7 14 12 30 28 15 6 23 25 2 31 18 11 3 27 24 9 19 5 26 0 4 10 17 13 21]    Fitness value: 324.7188322103662
2. [24 27 25 12 30 15 18 20 28 23 10 0 29 26 13 17 6 9 22 4 1 7 8 5 21 32 16 31 14 2 3 19 11]    Fitness value: 337.496502384419
3. [11 17 29 26 28 30 9 10 32 15 21 27 7 4 12 8 13 20 5 3 14 2 31 0 24 19 16 22 1 25 23 18 6]    Fitness value: 340.2679234841635
4. [14 26 15 1 21 8 23 27 18 32 4 12 16 7 13 3 31 20 22 24 5 30 29 28 0 25 11 9 19 10 6 2 17]    Fitness value: 355.58802355081076
```

And the second:

```
1. [22 20 1 8 29 32 16 7 14 12 30 28 15 6 23 25 2 31 18 11 3 27 24 9 19 5 26 0 4 10 17 13 21]    Fitness value: 320.9572496353372
2. [22 20 1 8 29 32 16 7 14 12 30 28 15 6 23 25 2 31 18 11 3 27 24 9 19 5 26 0 4 10 17 13 21]    Fitness value: 320.9572496353372
3. [11 17 29 26 28 30 9 10 32 15 21 27 7 4 12 8 13 20 5 3 14 2 31 0 24 19 16 22 1 25 23 18 6]    Fitness value: 354.2361876347537
4. [11 17 29 26 28 30 9 10 32 15 21 27 7 4 12 8 13 20 5 3 14 2 31 0 24 19 16 22 1 25 23 18 6]    Fitness value: 354.2361876347537
```

And the third:

```
1. [24 27 25 12 30 15 18 20 28 23 10 0 29 26 13 17 6 9 22 4 1 7 8 5 21 32 16 31 14 2 3 19 11]    Fitness value: 337.496502384419
2. [24 27 25 12 30 15 18 20 28 23 10 0 29 26 13 17 6 9 22 4 1 7 8 5 21 32 16 31 14 2 3 19 11]    Fitness value: 337.496502384419
3. [24 27 25 12 30 15 18 20 28 23 10 0 29 26 13 17 6 9 22 4 1 7 8 5 21 32 16 31 14 2 3 19 11]    Fitness value: 337.496502384419
4. [24 27 25 12 30 15 18 20 28 23 10 0 29 26 13 17 6 9 22 4 1 7 8 5 21 32 16 31 14 2 3 19 11]    Fitness value: 337.496502384419
5. [15 16 18 14 12 25 6 26 27 9 21 28 7 17 23 32 19 31 2 4 3 24 11 22 0 5 30 29 20 10 13 8 1]    Fitness value: 340.49473823049664
6. [15 16 18 14 12 25 6 26 27 9 21 28 7 17 23 32 19 31 2 4 3 24 11 22 0 5 30 29 20 10 13 8 1]    Fitness value: 340.49473823049664
7. [15 16 18 14 12 25 6 26 27 9 21 28 7 17 23 32 19 31 2 4 3 24 11 22 0 5 30 29 20 10 13 8 1]    Fitness value: 340.49473823049664
8. [15 16 18 14 12 25 6 26 27 9 21 28 7 17 23 32 19 31 2 4 3 24 11 22 0 5 30 29 20 10 13 8 1]    Fitness value: 340.49473823049664
```

You get the picture I think. Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Side note: such things are perfect for unit tests. You would start with having a dedicated method that provides the compare function; and then you could do all the testing you want on that. Meaning: first make sure that all your individual "parts" are fully correct; and only then, when the small elements work, throw them together. Don't try to solve a problem on the "overall" level; when you could focus on smaller aspects before. And well, your compare function compares array lengths?! Shouldnt it compare the fitness of each array?

Comment: It's not clear how you want to sort it, you appear to be sorting be the last item in a population?

Comment: It isn't to do with the sorting function, it is to do with how you are creating `popArr` in the first place. Try calling `System.err.println(popArr)` (intentionally not using `Arrays.toString()`) - I expect you will find that many of the child arrays' hash codes are the same.

Comment: `Comparator<double[]>` isn't a generic array. It is a concrete implementation of a generic interface, specialized for arrays. That's absolutely fine.

Comment: I think your Comparator is perfectly fine. probably as @AndyTurner implied... maybe you are not properly making copies of your arrays between iterators but just copying around references?

Comment: @Thanga well... yes? OP is trying to compare instances of `double[]`, so the type of the comparator is `Comparator<double[]>`, not `Comparator<double>`.

Comment: Simple demo of the fact that `Comparator<double[]>` is completely fine: http://ideone.com/2CmRan.

Comment: @AndyTurner Okay, so I tried some stuff. The comparator seems to be fine (it's supposed to compare the last index in the arrays as that is where the fitness value is stored, also Eclipse at least never argued about me using `<double[]>`) indeed as I tried the reproduction, mutation and crossover with simple made up arrays and they screwed up the ArrayList I've been working with. Thus I assume now that that's the problem. When running `System.err.println(popArr)` I do get the same hash code after the second iteration which I'm not sure is wrong as I keep working with one list over and over.

Comment: "I'm not sure is wrong" If your question is asking "why do I unexpectedly get the same array over and over", yes, it's wrong. If you do expect to get the same array over and over... I don't understand why you have a problem with the output.

Comment: @AndyTurner But wouldn't the hash code stay the same even if I change the values in the `double[][] popArr` if `popArr` is still the same?

Comment: The hashcode of `popArr` does; and the hashcodes of the elements of `popArr` do, but potentially in a different order. Ah, dammit. I realized that my "intentionally" comment before was wrong - it should have been using `Arrays.toString()`. That is embarrassing.

Comment: @AndyTurner Changed some things and now after running for 1000 generations it gives me fitness values ~200 which according to my lecturer is what we're aiming at with that particular GA. Since it's working, I will stop wondering why it does what it does and just go with it, so that I can concentrate on two other projects which will also be due soon. Thanks for all the help though I might get back to it some day.